# undefined local variable or method `mock' for main:Object

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I am using [Mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) for testing.

```
2.1.5 :047 > require 'mocha'
  => false
```

AFAIK it means `mocha` is already loaded and should be fine. Anyway, when mocking or stubbing:

```
2.1.5 :048 > mock
NameError: undefined local variable or method `mock' for main:Object
    from (irb):48
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./test/dummy/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from ./test/dummy/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2.1.5 :049 > Github.expects :repos
NoMethodError: undefined method `expects' for Github:Module
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/github_api-0.12.3/lib/github_api.rb:56:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):49
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./test/dummy/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from ./test/dummy/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2.1.5 :051 >   stub
NameError: undefined local variable or method `stub' for main:Object
    from (irb):51
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./test/dummy/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from ./test/dummy/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Does mocking should work in IRB or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error before I include `Mocha::API`. This will [include](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/blob/master/lib/mocha/api.rb#L18-22) appropriate Mocha's methods to your `Object`, `Module`, `Class` classes and add missed functionality to your irb session:

```
$ irb
Welcome to IRB. You are using ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]. Have fun ;)
>> require 'mocha/api' #=> true
>> include Mocha::API #=> Object
>> mock #=> #<Mock:0x2da1ce8>
>> stub #=> #<Mock:0x2d6a680>
>> Object.expects :something #=> #<Expectation:0x256e878 expected exactly once, not yet invoked: Object.something(any_parameters) >
```

Comment: It is not working too. Anyway, giving only code sample is a bad way to explain things.